# How can I make the animation smoother

Tags: css

I have made an animation in which the image floats.

But the image seems to be vibrating when reaching the end.

Here is the website where the image is [link](https://www.ankitsinghchauhan.tech/)

This is the CSS if the `div` wrapping the `img`

```
.newImg {
    position: relative;
    width: 472px;
    height: 414px;
    animation-name: updown;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    /* animation-delay: 1.5s; */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes updown {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
    }

    25% {
        top: 8px;
    }

    50% {
        top: 0px;
    }

    75% {
        top: 8px;
    }

    100% {
        top: 0px;
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vibration you see because of the top property. Try using translateY() instead. It will perform faster, animate smoother, and won't affect the layout.

```css
@keyframes updown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translateY(8px);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translateY(8px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```